# How to fix a while condition so it does not execute do part non-stop

Tags: c, do-while

Problem is that the program continues to ask for height even in the case where a number between 1 and 8 is entered. I am also having difficulty understanding why I need to restate "int height" after the while loop, but that's a side issue.

```
{
   do
   {
    int height = get_int("Height: \n");
   }
   while ('h'>8 || 'h'<1);

  int height;

  printf ("Stored: %d\n", height);
}
```

I expect that it presents the number entered to the user, but it doesn't get past requesting for input, despite the conditions in the while function.

Comment: `'h'` is an integer constant which is usually greater than `8`

Comment: What is `get_int()`

Comment: Change `'h'` to `height` (without quotes)

Comment: The condition is tautologously true. Replace single quotes with nothing and `h` with `height`.

Answer (score 2):

`'h'` is a constant. In [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) it will always have an integer value of `104`. So `'h' > 8` will always be true.

As for your second question. The `height` variable defined inside of the do-while loop is in a different scope. A new `height` is created at the start of each iteration and destroyed at the end of each iteration.

Defining `height` before the loop will make it accessible inside of and after the loop.

```
int height = 0;
do {
    height = get_int("Height: \n");
} while (height > 8 || height < 1);
printf("Stored: %d\n", height);
```

Try looking at C's [scope rules](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scope-rules-in-c/) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

In your condition:

```
while ('h'>8 || 'h'<1)
```

`'h'` is a character constant.  It has nothing to do with the variable `height`.  You're comparing this constant against 8 and 1.  In ASCII, the code for `'h'` is greater than 8, so the condition will always be true.

Also:

```
int height = get_int("Height: \n");
```

Having `height` declared inside of the loop means it ceases to exist outside of the loop, which include the loop conditional.  The `height`  you define later is a different variable than this one.

Move the definition of `height` outside of the loop, and use `height` in the comparison:

```
int height;
do
{
    height = get_int("Height: \n");
} while (height>8 || height<1);

printf ("Stored: %d\n", height);
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Your note about declaring it outside the loop is also very helpful.

Comment: @Nahom Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> do
> {
>    int height = get_int("Height: \n");
> }
> while ('h'>8 || 'h'<1);
> ```

the test is a constant expression, `'h'>8` is always true and '`h'<1` always false, so the test is always true, there is no reason the do while stops

note : `int height` is a local variable only existing in the do block

---

> int height;
>
> printf ("Stored: %d\n", height);

you print a non initialized variable

---

move the `int height;` before the do while and replace `int height = get_int("Height: \n");` by `height = get_int("Height: \n");`, and of course replace the test to check height value

Answer (score 0):

your test inside the while is never changing and is always true, the compiler is referring to 'h' as a char and is converting it to its ASCII code that is 104 (which is always greater than 8). the while in this code is for the compiler always like `while (104 > 8 || 104 < >);`. Also, you don't have to restate the `int height;`, the height variable is already declared.

you can change your code for something like:

```
{

do {
   int height = get_int("Height : \n");
} while ( height > 8 || height < 1);

printf ("Stored: %d\n", height);

}
```

Answer (score -3):

You should declare variable int high outside. Like this

Problem is that the program continues to ask for height even in the case where a number between 1 and 8 is entered. I am also having difficulty understanding why I need to restate "int height" after the while loop, but that's a side issue.

{

int height;
do

{

height = get_int("Height: \n");

}

while ('h'>8 || 'h'<1);

printf ("Stored: %d\n", height);

}